# PYTORCH - TENSORS issue - Mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (8x10 and 8x8)

Tags: python, math, matrix, pytorch, matrix-multiplication

[I know this question comes a lot, but I could not find any answer matching my use case]

[edit: please answer this question if you know about Pytorch, I know about matrix multiplication, this is not the issue here]

I feed N = 10 inputs made out of 8 floats to a 8 input layer

but I get that error

```
Mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (8x10 and 8x8)
```

What am I missing ?

I generate random data in my dataset

```
class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []
        self.input_size = 0
        for i in range(0,10):
            label = random.randint(0, 1)
            data = [random.uniform(0.0, 1.0) for _ in range(8)]
            self.data.append((data , label))
            self.input_size = len(data ) if self.input_size < len(encoded_text) else self.input_size
  
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        text, label = self.data[idx]
        return text, label
```

This is my model

```
class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.input = nn.Linear(input_size,hidden_size)
        self.hidden = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self, x):
        # padding is there as original dataset does not have full 8 floats inputs
        x_padded = pad_sequence(x, batch_first=True, padding_value=0).float()  
        output = self.input(x_padded) >>>>>>>> ERROR
        return torch.sigmoid(output)

def train_model(model, train_loader, criterion, optimizer, num_epochs):
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        for inputs, labels in train_loader:
            outputs = model(inputs)
```

The initialisation part

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    hidden_size = 8  # hidden size 
    output_size = 1  # binary classification 
    learning_rate = 0.001
    num_epochs = 10
    
    dataset = MyDataset()
    train_loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)
    
    input_size = dataset.input_size
    
    model = MyModel(input_size, hidden_size, output_size)
    criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
    train_model(model, train_loader, criterion, optimizer, num_epochs)`
```

This is a really simple beginner use case, nothing fancy

thanks for your help

[edit: the x input is made out of 8 tensors of 10 values but it should be 10 tensors of 8 values ]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was this line :

```
x_flattened = x_padded.view(x_padded.size(0), -1)
```

had to use this :

```
x_flattened = x_padded.view(x_padded.size(1), -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply a matrix p×q with a matrix q×r and the result will be a matrix p×r.

More explicitly:

You can multiply a matrix (p rows, q columns) with a matrix (q rows, r columns) and the result will have (p rows, r columns).

Notice how the number of ***columns*** of the matrix on the left must equal the number of ***rows*** of the matrix on the right.

[Wikipedia has a nice picture to visualise this.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication)

Examples:

- (8×10) times (10×12) gives (8x12);
- (8×10) times (10×10) gives (8x10);
- (8×8) times (8×10) gives (8x10);
- (10×8) times (8×8) gives (10x8);
- (8×10) times (8×8) doesn't work.

So there must have been an error in your reasoning if you thought you had to multiply these two matrices in that order.

Ask yourself these questions:

- What do these two matrices represent?
- Why do you want to multiply them?
- If you want to multiply them, how did you choose which matrix should be on the left and which on the right?
- What would the resulting matrix represent?

### Important note: matrix multiplication, function composition

##### Applying operations right-to-left

In mathematics, function composition is always written "right-to-left". If you have a vector x, and you apply function f, then you apply function g, then the result is written

g(f(x)) or (g∘f)(x)

note how g appears on the left and f on the right although f is applied first.

Matrices can represent linear functions, and matrix multiplication corresponds to function composition, so if matrix A represents linear function f and matrix B represents linear function g, and column vector X represents vector x, then g(f(x)) must be calculated as BAX, not ABX.

Comment: I know about matrices, I been to school, this does not tell me how to fix the code, it is pytorch stuff and I am a beginner, why is this code messing matrices ? why are the tensors having only 6 values instead of 8 ?

Comment: @phil I don't understand what youvmean by "6 values instead of 8".

Comment: @phil Did you read the four questions "Ask yourself those questions:" in my answer? Can you answer these questions?

Comment: please see the attached pictures, tensors of 8x10 are created somehow from my 10x8 inputs, THIS MAKES NO SENSE